# how to limit the foreignkey dropdown with constraints?

Tags: django, django-admin

I have a database which keeps track of interaction between two different teams (represented in the admin interface by two different groups). For some fields, i have a foreignkey to Users database, and i would like to limit the dropdown people to only the specific groups.

If anyone have any suggestions, it would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're looking for [`limit_choices_to`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to).

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! However, i think the user-groups relationship resides on different tables in django admin, how would i filter in that case?

Comment: With `Q` objects. `Q(group__icontains=u'user')`

Comment: Hey Ignacio, I'm still kinda confused on how to do this. After digging through the code for auth module further, i have found that groups is defined in User class as follows: groups = models.ManyToManyField(Group, verbose_name=_('groups'), blank=True,). The query is based on Users, so i would like to check whether the current User in question is in group "Legal". Note that the Group model have a ID, so the name is not stored in User directly. Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: `ForeignKey(User, limit_choices_to={'groups__name': u'Legal'}, ...)`

Comment: What if I want it to be filtered not based on a constant, but based on another model field??? Meaning: What if I want access to 'self' in this Q object?

Comment: This doesn't let you access the request if you want i.e. to filter objects based on the current user. use answers from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179129 to do that.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the underlaying queryset for the form field: [How do I filter ForeignKey choices in a Django ModelForm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291945/how-do-i-filter-foreignkey-choices-in-a-django-modelform)

Comment: It seems to say that it should be done in the view, but i'm not sure how to access the view, the only thing i have access to is the model class and the modeladmin class. Any particular directional suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should use a custom form and do it in the form's `__init__`!    
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["user"].queryset = User.objects.filter(...)

Answer (score 3):

To override the choices for a foreign key field in Django admin app, write a [`formfield_for_foreignkey`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) method.

Comment: Another alternative, in case the choices depend on the model instance: https://stackoverflow.com/a/949290