# How do i change choices in a DjangoAdmin field if i change another field?

Tags: python, django, admin, models

Im creating a db for an hotel and i want to be able to have a field listing all Seasons related (FK) to the hotel selected in the previous field.

```
class PriceTable(models.Model):
    client = models.ForeignKey(Cliente, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    year = models.ForeignKey(Ano, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    season_price = models.ForeignKey(SeasonPrice, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class SeasonPrice(models.Model):
    season = models.ForeignKey(Season, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Season(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    date_in = models.DateField()
    date_end = models.DateField()
    hotel = models.ForeignKey(Hotel, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

In django admin page how can i list in season_price all the seasons that have a foreign key of the hotel i just choose?
Here is an image to better understand what i want to acomplish:[Django admin explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XogTX.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [filter foreignkey field in django admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179129/filter-foreignkey-field-in-django-admin)

Comment: yes, i think that solves my problem i will give it a try

Answer (score 0):

Usually, I always use JQuery to solve this kind of problems. Here is the example, which is a simple example, you have to change the necessary part.

Description:

```
Select a user in the page, and the article will change to the articles belong to the selected user.
```

The urls.py

```
from TestDjango.testdb import testdb, getArticlesByUser
urlpatterns = [
    ......
    url(r'^testdb/$', testdb, name='testdb'),
    url(r'^getarticles/$', getArticlesByUser, name='get_art'),
    ......
]
```

testdb.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from Articles.models import Articles
from Users.models import Users

def testdb(request):
    context = {
        'users': Users.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, "Users/list.html", context)


def getArticlesByUser(request):
    # get parameters from page - Users/list.html
    user_id = request.GET.get('user_id', None)

    # get data from database by using "user_id"
    list_articles = Articles.objects.filter(user_id=user_id)

    str_alltitle = ""
    for item in list_articles:
        str_alltitle += '<option value="' + str(item.id) + '"> ' + item.title + ' </option> '

    # return a json response to the html
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    return JsonResponse({'articles': str_alltitle})
```

list.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}
    List Articles By User ID - User
{% endblock %}

{% block mainbody %}
<p>
    <span>User:</span>
    <select id="user" name="user_id">
        <option value="">---Empty---</option>
        {% for user in users %}
            <option value="{{ user.id }}" > {{ user.email }} </option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</p>
<p>
    <span>Articles:</span>
    <select id="article" name="article_id"></select>
</p>
{% endblock %}

{% block scriptsection %}
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#user').bind('change', function () {

   $.ajax({
      url: '/getarticles/?user_id='+ this.value,
      type: 'GET',
      success: function (json) {
          $('#article').html(json['articles'])
      }
  });
});

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

This is working in my computer, I use python 3.4 and Django 1.10.4!