# Restrict values that appear in Django admin select box

Tags: python, django

In Django 1.11, I have 2 models, `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    extra = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class Bar(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    extra_foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

My `admin.py` looks like this:

```
class BarInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Bar
    fields = ('name', 'extra_foo')

class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields('name')
    inlines = [BarInline]
```

My problem is that the in the Bar inline form, the dropdown for `extra_foo` shows *all* of my existing `Foo`s. I want it to only show `Foo`s for which `extra` is `true`. How can I modify the admin to restrict the available options in a select box to a subset of the whole?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, you can use `render_change_form`

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     def render_change_form(self, request, context, *args, **kwargs):
         context['adminform'].form.fields['extra_foo'].queryset = Foo.objects.filter(extra=True)
         return super(FooAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, *args, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

If you want this to be global then have a look at [limit_choices_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.limit_choices_to)

`extra_foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, limit_choices_to={'extra': True})`

Credit : [filter foreignkey field in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179129/filter-foreignkey-field-in-django-admin)

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that by using `limit_choices_to`. Change this line:

```
extra_foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

to:

```
extra_foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, limit_choices_to={'extra': True})
```

This will limit the choices for `extra_foo` to `Foo` objects that have the property `extra` set to `True`.

This approach will however limit the choices not only in the admin but also beyond. If you need to adjust only the admin, you need a different approach.