# Self-referencing foreign keys are listing everything if the value is null in Django-admin Page

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I have a django model as below:

```
class Words(models.Model):
    bare = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    accented = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    derived_from_word = models.ForeignKey('self', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True, related_name='derived_words',
    related_query_name='derived_word')
```

There is a field derived_from_word which shows that some of the words are derived from some other word. If it is not derived from any word so the field value is **NULL**.

What issue i am having that when i register this model in the django-admin and when i opened any of the word for editing, the derived_from_word field is listing all the words and i can not find a way for it to list only the derived word or the NULL value. Due to high load of the words the drop down list is making the page unresponsive.

Comment: This is how foreign keys are handled by model forms and the admin. Are you saying that you want the field to not be editable?

Comment: yes more or less so.

Comment: You can include the field in `readonly_fields` if you don't want to render a select input for it

Answer (score 1):

Since Django 2.0 you can use [`autocomplete_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.autocomplete_fields) to change the select to an auto complete search field that will load options asynchronously

```
class WordsAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['bare', 'accented']
    autocomplete_fields = ['derived_from_word']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this for filtering your query set: [filter foreignkey field in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179129/filter-foreignkey-field-in-django-admin)

Or use the "raw_id_fields" variable for your ModelAdmin to be able to just enter the ID of your instance.