# How to create a model in Django based on the instance of another model, but filtered

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I am new to Django, I am searching a way to create a model in Django based on the instance of another model, but filtered.

I have a table called Person, which has name and role, in my models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):

id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True) 
name = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
role = models.CharField(max_length=100) 
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    db_table = 'person'
```

What I want is to be able in my admin.py to call some subclass, which will display only actors (role="actors"):

```
@admin.register(Actor)
class Actor(admin.ModelAdmin):...
```

Is it possible? Or do I have to create one more table only with actors?

I know that I can use `list_filter = ('role',)`, but this is not what I am searching for, I need actors exclusively.

I see solution as something like this:

```
class Actor(models.Model):
    objects = Person.objects.filter(role='actor')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'actor'
```

or

```
class Actor(Person):
    self.objects.filter(role='actor')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'actor'
```

That obviousely does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Proxy model for this:

```
class ActorManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().filter(role='actors')

class Actor(Person):
    objects = ActorManager()
    
    class Meta:
        proxy = True
```

Proxy models are just a proxy of the inherited model (Person here) i.e. no new table is created. Here we have created a custom manager so that the roles are always filtered. Now just register this model to the admin site. References: [Proxy Models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#proxy-models), [Custom Managers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers)

Comment: I know need to understand how to use this model as a field in another model, which is connected to original Person through intermediate table, if i just use `actors = models.ManyToManyField('Actor', through=FilmWorkPerson)` I get an error (does not have a foreign key to ). If you want I can make one more separate question to which you can answer :)

Comment: Don't make a `ForeignKey` to this model, Make a `ForeignKey` to `Person`

Comment: but then it will show all persons but not only actors

Comment: @MStikh look at this question [filter foreignkey field in django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179129/filter-foreignkey-field-in-django-admin). It may help you.

Comment: Now when I try add new entry to the actors, admin panel does not let me to do it: Film work person with this Movie already exists.