# Custom Query for Django ModelChoiceField using user.get_profile()

Tags: django, user-profile, django-queryset

I am wondering how to access a user's profile when creating the
queryset for a ModelChoiceField. I would like to be able to use the
ModelChoiceField to display contacts from another table based on a
parameter saved in the user profile i.e.

```
who = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Contacts.objects.filter(id__exact=request.user.get_profile().main_company))
```

Is there a better way to do this (beyond an ajax picker in the
template)?

Greg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Those interested I was able to come up with a solution from the following SO discussions:

[How do I access the request object or any other variable in a form's clean() method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057252/django-how-do-i-access-the-request-object-or-any-other-variable-in-a-forms-clea/1057640#1057640)

[Django: accessing the model instance from within ModelAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949268/django-accessing-the-model-instance-from-within-modeladmin/949290#949290)

```
class InspectionRequestForm(ModelForm):
    ....
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
            super(InspectionRequestForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            companyid = self.request.user.get_profile().main_contactnum.clientid.idflcustomernum
            self.fields['who'].queryset = Contacts.objects.filter(clientid__exact=companyid)
```

My View:

Save Form (Not as necessary to include request=request here, but just in case)

```
form = InspectionRequestForm(request.POST, request=request)
```

Or Empty Form

```
form = InspectionRequestForm(request=request)
```

Thanks to Daniel Roseman for both of the previous answers.

https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman