# How do I perform a reverse foreign key lookup using in django's admin fields?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-filer

I'm using [django-filer](http://django-filer.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.4/) on a project and have a model that looks like this:

```
from django.db import models
from filer.fields.folder import FilerFolderField

class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    logo = FilerFolderField()
```

For `company/admin.py`, I'd like to override the `logo` field so that I'm able to list the files in the folder. For example, in the shell, I can do this:

```
>>> from companies.models import Company
>>> c = Company.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> c.logo
<Folder: company a logos>
>>> c.logo.files
[<Image: logo-black.jpg>, <Image: logo-white.jpg>]
```

So, for example, when I edit a company object, I'd like to see an inline form with a logo in each field.

But I'm not sure how to do this in my `CompanyAdmin`; I've looked at both [`formfield_for_foreignkey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) and [`formfield_for_dbfield`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L116), but it's not clear to me from either one how I would get the primary key of the model instance being edited so I can perform the lookup.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating your own CompanyLogo form field subclassing the django-filer field. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949268/django-accessing-the-model-instance-from-within-modeladmin) will provide more information on how to do the reverse-foreign-key lookup.