# How do I get current model instance in related ModelForm

Tags: django

If I have the following Model, ModelAdmin and ModelForm, how do I get current `Order` (the Order instance user's changing) in `clean` method

```
class Order(models.Model)
    # Order Model

class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = OrderAdminForm

class OrderAdminForm(forms.ModelForm)
    class Meta:
        model = Order

    def clean(self):
        # How do I get current the Order instance I'm editing here ?

admin.site.register(Order, OrderAdmin)
```

Comment: whats meaning of order? there is no ordering in clean method

Comment: I want to get the `Order` instance I'm currently editing in clean method

Comment: Have you looked at [this post to see if it answers your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949268/django-accessing-the-model-instance-from-within-modeladmin)

Comment: Oh sorry. I think you means `order by`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a ModelForm, the instance is accessible via self.instance

Comment: How to get the instance of modelform_1 into modelform_2?